# Run terminated flutter app from notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending FCM notifications from Kotlin native code in a Flutter app.
How can I open a Flutter terminated app by clicking on the notification that I have send through Kotlin native code?
Is there any way to achieve it?

**Solution: I have solved it by using**

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message)  {

if (message != null) { // your logic }      

});
```